# Clickable HTML table rows that POST to a PHP popup window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an HTML table that has rows generated with PHP and populated with MySQL data. I want the rows to be clickable, where onclick they open a new window with the MySQL data for that row.

What method can I use to POST a value on click and open the PHP page in a new window without disturbing the parent page?
My rows are generated similar to this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
        <tr onclick=\"openDetails(" . $row['id'] . ")\"> //openDetails() does nothing for now…
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['ser'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['part'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
```

`openDetails();` does nothing but I thought JS (I'm open to JQuery solutions) was the key. The overall idea is that someone clicks the row and they get assets_details.php (Which will query for `WHERE id=$_POST['id']` and populate a form) in a new window where they can edit and submit the information. If POST isn't possible a `$_SESSION` variable would do, I just don't know how to set either "onclick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @RamRaider for the suggestions but I know nothing of ajax and I'm afraid to use code that I don't fully understand.

I came up with this solution though. I wrapped the table in a form and created a hidden input that is set and submitted onclick for the row.

```
<form target='_blank' name='getID' method='POST' action='asset_details.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='id'>
<table>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
        <tr onclick=\"selectID('" . $row['id'] . "')\">
            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['ser'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['part'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>";
```

The JS:

```
function selectID(id) {
    document.getID.id.value = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    document.getElementsByName('getID')[0].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

normally for calling a method with parameter in javascript, the parameter should be in quotes,

change

```
<tr onclick=\"openDetails(" . $row['id'] . ")\">
```

to

```
<tr onclick=\"openDetails('" . $row['id'] . "')\">
```

Comment: Even so, I don't have an openDetails() function defined. I do not know how to POST data to a new window with JS.

Comment: If the parameter is an integer or an object of some sort there is no need for quotes around it - for a string though it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would not use an inline function but register the function for all rows using a method such as `document.querySelectorAll` which can get the id from an attribute on the `TR` object/element. Your function ( `openDetails` ) would then post, via ajax, to your backend script which would do whatever processing it had to do before returning a response in whatever format you like.

Some pseudo code to show the flow you would take. How you process the data is then up to you - you could pop up a dialog on screen ( ie: lightbox style ), flash a message somewhere, add a new table row etc Please note, the ajax function was written here just now to show the idea and I can make no guarantees that it will all work 'as is'

```
html/php
--------
I would include the id in a dataset value like this so that the javascript can get the value when the tr is clicked.
<tr data-id='".$row['id']."'>


javascript
----------
function initialise(){
    /* find all table rows and assign a listener function */
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    for( var n in col ) if( n && col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ){
        col[n].addEventListener('click',openDetails,false);
    }
}

function openDetails(event){
    /* get the specific id from the table row using it's dataset-id value */
    var id=this.dataset.id;
    /* pseudo ajax method */
    ajax.call( this, '/assets_details.php',{ 'callback':opendetails_callback, 'params':{ 'id':id } } );
}

function ajax(url,options){
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params=[];
    for( var n in options.params ) params.push( n+'='+options.params[n] );

    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( req.readyState && req.status==200 ) {
           /* invoke callback function with data returned from asset_details.php */
           options.callback.call( this, req.response );
        }
    }
    req.open( 'POST', url, true );
    req.send( params.join('&') )
}

function opendetails_callback( response ){
    /* You would use the callback to create the new content on screen */
    alert( response );
}

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initialise, false );
```

The backend script would listen for POSTed data and respond accordingly.

```
assets_details.php
------------------
<?php
    /* include your functions etc */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){ 

        /* Process your data and send response: example */
        echo json_encode( $_POST ); 
    }
?>
```