# Clickable HTML row that POSTs variables to a different PHP script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating an HTML table in which I display data from a database. I want to be able to click a whole row and to execute a PHP script with the data from that row as variables, but I don't know how to POST the values in the table.

My table is created like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style='background-color:antiquewhite'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>         

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
           while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_object()) {
             ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo "{$row->ID} " ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "{$row->Address} " ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "{$row->Customer_Name} " ?></td>          

      </tr>
 <?php   }

      ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have found this older question, but I think the solution has some syntax issues which I can't get my head around:

[Clickable HTML table rows that POST to a PHP popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273755/clickable-html-table-rows-that-post-to-a-php-popup-window)

I tried something like this:

```
<form target='_blank' name='getID' method='POST' action='asset_details.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' id='id'>
<table>
  <?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
        <tr onclick=\"selectID('" . $row['id'] . "')\">
            <td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Customer_Name'] . "</td>
        </tr>"; ?>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript section:

```
function selectID(id) {
    document.getID.id.value = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    document.getElementsByName('getID')[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: Make an ajax post? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @DevinGray Unfortunately I'm not really good with ajax so I'd try another method if possible.

Comment: You could use a form inside the foreach loop with input values as $row[ID] etc, then write some js to submit each form on click to a php script. But I would say Ajax is your better option here

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 'this' keyword in javascript.
I have done an example for you...
 save it as index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .tr_hov:hover{
                background-color:green;
            }           
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function runajax(obj){
                var val = $(obj).find('td:first').text();
                $.post('demo.php',{id:val},function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                });

            }   
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<table class="table table-hover" style='background-color:antiquewhite' border='1'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>         

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



      <?php

      $row = array(
      'one' => array('id' => '100' , 'name' => 'John' , 'addr' => 'America'),
      'two' => array('id' => '101' , 'name' => 'Bush' , 'addr' => 'Briton'),
      'three' => array('id' => '102' , 'name' => 'Deedi' , 'addr' => 'China'),
      'four' => array('id' => '103' , 'name' => 'Jasica' , 'addr' => 'Japan')
      );

           foreach ($row as $x) {
   echo   "<tr class='tr_hov' onclick=\"runajax(this)\">
        <td>{$x['id']}</td>
        <td>{$x['name']}</td>
        <td>{$x['addr']}</td>          

      </tr>";
    }

      ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

save this page as demo.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
?>
```

I thing it helps you.